# How to fix "(Song Title) is not recognized in output screen"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am writing a music program but there are some trouble here that I could not open the music file even though I have downloaded it in my pc and put my c++ program together with the music in one file.

I have tried to convert it into a wav file instead of the default file type given upon installation of the music

```
class Music
{
private:
int song; //song selection
public: 
void Song_Name() //function for song selection    
{
do
{
cout<<"These are the music available: "<<endl<<endl;
cout<<"1. American Teen (Khalid) "<<endl;
cout<<"2. All We Know (Chainsmokers) "<<endl;
cout<<"3. Born To Be Yours (Kygo) "<<endl;
cout<<"4. Bodak Yellow (Cardi-B) "<<endl;
cout<<"5. Bad Guy (Billie Eilish) "<<endl;
if(song==1)
{
 system("Khalid - American Teen (Official Music Video).mp3");
}
}while(isdigit(song)!=0); //repeat again if alphabet is inputted
}
};
```

Expected the program will open and play the downloaded song but it shows that "(Song Title) is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Comment: The [`std::system`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) function executes a *program*. The easiest way to play a sound file using external programs depend on you OS.

Answer (score 0):

```
system("Khalid - American Teen (Official Music Video).mp3");
```

should be something like

```
system("MUSIC_PLAYER \"Khalid - American Teen (Official Music Video).mp3\"");
```

where MUSIC_PLAYER is the name of a program on your computer that plays music. Even then there is plenty that could go wrong here.

A piece of unasked for advice, I don't think your project is going to be marked on your ability to play music files, and looking at the snippet of code you've posted I can see you have something to learn about how to write good quality code. It's your ability to write well conceived, well organised code that will get you good marks. So maybe choose a project that doesn't depend on your ability to play music files, that's not the point of what you are being asked to do.